# Saving KDTree object in Python?

Tags: python, serialization, numpy, scipy, pickle

I am using Scipy's KDTree implementation to read a large file of 300 MB. Now, is there a way I can just save the datastructure to disk and load it again or am I stuck with reading raw points from file and constructing the data structure each time I start my program? I am constructing the KDTree as follows:

```
def buildKDTree(self):
        self.kdpoints = numpy.fromfile("All", sep=' ')
        self.kdpoints.shape = self.kdpoints.size / self.NDIM, NDIM
        self.kdtree = KDTree(self.kdpoints, leafsize = self.kdpoints.shape[0]+1)
        print "Preparing KDTree... Ready!"
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: have you tried pickling?

Comment: When I tried to use cPickle on a KDTree object, I get an error on my machine

Answer (score 14, accepted):

KDtree uses nested classes to define its node types (innernode, leafnode).  Pickle only works on module-level class definitions, so a nested class trips it up:

```
import cPickle

class Foo(object):
    class Bar(object):
        pass

obj = Foo.Bar()
print obj.__class__
cPickle.dumps(obj)

<class '__main__.Bar'>
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Bar'>: attribute lookup __main__.Bar failed
```

However, there is a (hacky) workaround by monkey-patching the class definitions into the `scipy.spatial.kdtree` at module scope so the pickler can find them.  If all of your code which reads and writes pickled KDtree objects installs these patches, this hack should work fine:

```
import cPickle
import numpy
from scipy.spatial import kdtree

# patch module-level attribute to enable pickle to work
kdtree.node = kdtree.KDTree.node
kdtree.leafnode = kdtree.KDTree.leafnode
kdtree.innernode = kdtree.KDTree.innernode

x, y = numpy.mgrid[0:5, 2:8]
t1 = kdtree.KDTree(zip(x.ravel(), y.ravel()))
r1 = t1.query([3.4, 4.1])
raw = cPickle.dumps(t1)

# read in the pickled tree
t2 = cPickle.loads(raw)
r2 = t2.query([3.4, 4.1])
print t1.tree.__class__
print repr(raw)[:70]
print t1.data[r1[1]], t2.data[r2[1]]
```

Output:

```
<class 'scipy.spatial.kdtree.innernode'>
"ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\np1\n(cscipy.spatial.kdtree\nKDTree\np2\nc_
[3 4] [3 4]
```

Comment: would you have a patch for the cython cKDTree too ?

Comment: @Denis Unfortunately I don't have a patch for cKDTree. Some form of save/load method should be possible, but would be more custom since [cKDTree](http://svn.scipy.org/svn/scipy/trunk/scipy/spatial/ckdtree.pyx) nodes are malloc'd structs, not classes.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error:
"maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

In fairness my tree is calculated on a 1,000,000 long list of 5d co-ordinates, as it only takes a few minutes to calculate from that array (the array itself I can save and load via numpy) I think I'll have to live with that.

Comment: Very nice solution, will this work for other types? and how can you research which types to expose this way?