# Time-efficient way to find connected spheres paths in Python

Tags: python, graph-theory, igraph, graph-tool, networkit

I have written a code to find connected spheres paths using *NetworkX* library in **Python**. For doing so, I need to find distances between the spheres before using the graph. This part of the code (calculation section (the *numba* function) --> finding distances and connections) led to memory leaks when using arrays in parallel scheme by *numba* (I had this problem when using `np.linalg` or `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`, too). So, I wrote a non-parallel *numba* code using lists to do so. Now, it is memory-friendly **but** consumes a much time to calculate these distances (*it consumes just ~10-20% of 16GB memory and ~30-40% of each CPU cores of my 4-cores CPU machine*). For example, when I was testing on ~12000 data volume, it took less than one second for each of the calculation section and the *NetworkX* graph creation and for ~550000 data volume, it took around 25 minutes for calculation section (*numba* part) and 7 seconds for graph creation and getting the output list.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import networkx as nx


radii = np.load('rad_dist_12000.npy')
poss = np.load('pos_dist_12000.npy')


@nb.njit("(Tuple([float64[:, ::1], float64[:, ::1]]))(float64[::1], float64[:, ::1])", parallel=True)
def distances_numba_parallel(radii, poss):
    radii_arr = np.zeros((radii.shape[0], radii.shape[0]), dtype=np.float64)
    poss_arr = np.zeros((poss.shape[0], poss.shape[0]), dtype=np.float64)
    for i in nb.prange(radii.shape[0] - 1):
        for j in range(i+1, radii.shape[0]):
            radii_arr[i, j] = radii[i] + radii[j]
            poss_arr[i, j] = ((poss[i, 0] - poss[j, 0]) ** 2 + (poss[i, 1] - poss[j, 1]) ** 2 + (poss[i, 2] - poss[j, 2]) ** 2) ** 0.5
    return radii_arr, poss_arr


@nb.njit("(List(UniTuple(int64, 2)))(float64[::1], float64[:, ::1])")
def distances_numba_non_parallel(radii, poss):
    connections = []
    for i in range(radii.shape[0] - 1):
        connections.append((i, i))
        for j in range(i+1, radii.shape[0]):
            radii_arr_ij = radii[i] + radii[j]
            poss_arr_ij = ((poss[i, 0] - poss[j, 0]) ** 2 + (poss[i, 1] - poss[j, 1]) ** 2 + (poss[i, 2] - poss[j, 2]) ** 2) ** 0.5
            if poss_arr_ij <= radii_arr_ij:
                connections.append((i, j))
    return connections


def connected_spheres_path(radii, poss):
    
    # in parallel mode
    # maximum_distances, distances = distances_numba_parallel(radii, poss)
    # connections = distances <= maximum_distances
    # connections[np.tril_indices_from(connections, -1)] = False
    
    # in non-parallel mode
    connections = distances_numba_non_parallel(radii, poss)

    G = nx.Graph(connections)
    return list(nx.connected_components(G))
```

My datasets will contain maximum of 10 millions spheres (data are positions and radii), mostly, up to 1 millions; As it is mentioned above, the most part of the consumed time is related to the calculation section. I have little experience using graphs and don't know if (and how) it can be handled much faster using all CPU cores or RAM capacity (*max 12GB*) or ***if it can be calculated internally*** (*I doubt that it is needed to calculate and find the connected spheres separately before using graphs*) using other Python libraries such as *graph-tool*, *igraph*, and *netwrokit* to do all the process in `C` or `C++` in an efficient way.
I would be grateful for any suggested answer that can make my code faster for large data volumes (**performance is the first priority**; *if much memory capacities are needed for large data volumes, mentioning (some benchmarks) its amounts will be helpful*).

---

### Update:

Since **just** using *tree*s will not be helpful enough to improve the performance, I have written an advanced optimized code to improve the calculation section speed by combining tree-based algorithms and numba jitting.
Now, I am curious ***if it can be calculated internally*** (*calculation section is an integral part and basic need for such graphing*) by other Python libraries such as *graph-tool*, *igraph*, and *netwrokit* to do all the process in `C` or `C++` in an efficient way.

---

### Data

radii: [12000](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17fE-e0drbJKWILipIit_ZCEbp--LPeWE/view?usp=sharing), [50000](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p7ptP1O9jIUceXjUug71zzvfFx9zxUJQ/view?usp=sharing), [550000](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZcfCzKH3isvTCvQTTjrDrNmZuInIZgxV/view?usp=sharing)
poss:  [12000](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19wG1TbKkrExlUGSg6qT6VfyTLHPZygm3/view?usp=sharing), [50000](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17SMC7ivtdGNNs9cd1raXOUWX4zi6Xxqq/view?usp=sharing), [550000](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QYkas3L2Azed5795_V-EosruVmSegRLy/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are computing the pairwise distance between all points, that's N^2 calculations, which will take a very long time for sufficiently many data points.

If you can place an upper bound on the distance you need to consider for any two points, then there are some nice data structures for finding pairs of neighbors in a set of points.  If you already have `scipy` installed, then the most convenient structure to reach for is the `KDTree` (or the optimized version, [`cKDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html)). ([Read more here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree))

The basic recipe is:

- Load your point set into the KDTree.
- Ask the KDTree for all pairs of points which are within some maximum distance from each other.
- Calculate the actual distances between each of the returned points.
- Compare those distances with the summed radii associated with the point pair. Drop the pairs whose distances are too large.

Finally, you need to determine the clusters of spheres.  Your question mentions "paths", but in your example code you're only concerned with connected components.  Of course you can use `networkx` or `graph-tool` for that, but maybe that's overkill.

If connected components are all you need, then you don't even need a proper graph data structure. You just need a way to find the groups of linked nodes, without maintaining the specific connections that linked them.  Again, `scipy` has a nice tool: [`DisjointSet`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.DisjointSet.html). ([Read more here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure))

Here is a complete example.  The execution time depends on not only the number of points, but how "dense" they are.  I tried some reasonable (I think) test data with  1M points, which took 24 seconds to process on my laptop.

Your example data (the largest of the sets provided above) takes longer: about 45 seconds.  The KDTree finds 312M pairs of points to consider, of which fewer than 1M are actually valid connections.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import DisjointSet

## Example data (2D)
## N = 1000
# D = 2
# max_point = 1000
# min_radius = 10
# max_radius = 20
# points = np.random.randint(0, max_point, size=(N, D))
# radii = np.random.randint(min_radius, max_radius+1, size=N)

## Example data (3D)
# N = 1_000_000
# D = 3
# max_point = 3000
# min_radius = 10
# max_radius = 20
# points = np.random.randint(0, max_point, size=(N, D))
# radii = np.random.randint(min_radius, max_radius+1, size=N)


# Question data (3D)
points = np.load('b (556024).npy')
radii = np.load('a (556024).npy')
N = len(points)

# Load into a KD tree and extract all pairs which could possibly be linked
# (using the maximum radius as the upper bound of the search distance.)
kd = cKDTree(points)
pairs = kd.query_pairs(2 * radii.max(), output_type='ndarray')

def filter_pairs(pairs):
    # Calculate the distance between each pair of points
    vectors = points[pairs[:, 1]] - points[pairs[:, 0]]
    distances = np.linalg.norm(vectors, axis=1)

    # Drop the pairs whose summed radii aren't large enough
    # to span the distance between the points.
    thresholds = radii[pairs].sum(axis=1)
    return pairs[distances <= thresholds]

# We could do this in one big step
# ...but that might require lots of RAM.
# It's cheaper to do it in big chunks, in a loop.
fp = []
CHUNK = 1_000_000
for i in range(0, len(pairs), CHUNK):
    fp.append(filter_pairs(pairs[i:i+CHUNK]))
filtered_pairs = np.concatenate(fp)

# Load the pairs into a DisjointSet (a.k.a. UnionFind)
# data structure and extract the groups.
ds = DisjointSet(range(N))
for u, v in filtered_pairs:
    ds.merge(u, v)
connected_sets = list(ds.subsets())

print(f"Found {len(connected_sets)} sets of circles/spheres")
```

Just for fun, here's a visualization of the 2D test data:

```
from bokeh.plotting import output_notebook, figure, show
output_notebook()

p = figure()
p.circle(*points.T, radius=radii, fill_alpha=0.25)
p.segment(*points[filtered_pairs[:, 0]].T,
          *points[filtered_pairs[:, 1]].T,
          line_color='red')
show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution; It was a good one. I couldn't apply it on the largest prepared data volume (i.e. 550000) due to `MemoryError: bad allocation` in `scipy.spatial._ckdtree.cKDTree.query_pairs` which I expected by these trees (my available RAM ~12GB); Trees depend on the max radii size (the radii range), so, if we have just one big sphere, it will consume a very large RAM capacity. Could you please write your machine specifications? How much RAM your laptop have? Could `N` be `len(filtered_pairs)` instead of `len(points)`? For 550000 data volume, what number did you choose for the CHUNK?

Comment: I am surprised. I ran that code on my laptop. A Mac with 32GB of RAM.

Comment: I ran the code with the data you supplied, exactly as you see it above. In my testing, it does not use much RAM.

Comment: I did not profile the memory usage. Perhaps one thing you can try is to experiment with the initialization settings for the KDTree. That class has some options which I did not experiment with. 

Another option is to try using BallTree from sklearn. I notice that you are already familiar with it, due to your comment on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30447355/162094

Comment: Okay, here’s another idea. Use TWO KDTrees. In the first, load all points. In the second, load only 10%of the points. Then use query_ball_tree to find all neighbors from those 10% of points (i) to points in the full set (j). (Discard results where i=j) Then repeat for the next 10% of points, and so on. That strategy requires 10x more queries, but may reduce the required RAM for each one.

Comment: In the worst case, you can just execute a separate query for every point (via the query() method). That will take time, but it should still be much better than N^2 calculations!

Answer (score 1):

> to find connected spheres using NetworkX library in Python.  For
> doing so, I need to find distances between the spheres

Are you calculating the distance between every pair of spheres?

If all you need is to know the pairs of spheres that touch, or maybe that overlap, then you do NOT need to calculate the distance between every pair of spheres, only ones that are in reasonable proximity to each other.  The standard way of handling this it to use an octree https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree

This takes some time to set up, but once you have it, you can find quickly all the spheres that are close but none that are two far away.  A reasonable distance would be twice the radius of the largest sphere.  For large dataset the improvement in performance can be spectacular

[image]

( For more details about this test https://github.com/JamesBremner/quadtree )

So, the complete algorithm to find the `paths` through the connected spheres can be broken out into four conceptual steps

1. Find the connected spheres, using an octree to optimize finding them.  Instead of searching through every pair of spheres, loop over the spheres and search through the spheres in the same octree cell.  For more details on how to make this work you might want to look at the C++ code at https://github.com/JamesBremner/quadtree
2. Create the adjacency matrix of connected spheres.  Conceptually this is a separate step, however, you will probably want to do that as you search for connected sphere in the first step.  Construct an empty adjacency matrix N by N where N is the number of spheres.  Each time you find a pair of connected spheres, fill in in matrix.
3. Load the matrix into a graph library.  It may be more efficient to simply add the link between two connected spheres directly into the library and let it build the adjacency matrix.
4. Use the graph library methods to find the path.

Comment: The scipy library already implements a convenient k-d tree, so he need not implement an octree himself.  Also, he might not need a graph library after all.  With a little help from scipy, a reasonable solution is feasible in ~20 lines.  Scipy has a lot of hidden gems!